# Querying non-unicode data in SQL Server using collation hint

Tags: sql-server-2008, collation

I'm trying to find a way to read(select) the data from a table that has a `varchar` datatype. The data is in Tibetan language. When I query the data it get `???`s of different lengths. Surprisingly, when I use the predicate to filter on the string, it does it successfully but the output is still `???`. This means that SQL Server is able to understand the filter criteria but it's just not able to show me the output. I'm really not sure what am I missing here.

Let me share the sample here:

```
--create this table in database with collation set to
--Latin1_General_100_CI_AS or SQL_Latin1_General_100_CI_AS

CREATE TABLE Locations
(Place varchar(64)NOT NULL);  
GO 

INSERT into Locations_2(Place) VALUES ('ཡུན་རིང་འཇལ་རྒྱུ་མ་བྱུང་།')    
INSERT into Locations_2(Place) VALUES ('ཁྱེད་རང་ལུང་པ་ག་ནས་ཡིམ།')  
INSERT into Locations_2(Place) VALUES ('ཤོགས་པ་བདེ་ལེགས།')
GO

SELECT place collate Chinese_PRC_CI_AI from locations 
where place=N'ཤོགས་པ་བདེ་ལེགས།'
```

This shows me nothing. But the query below shows the output as `?????????`
The only difference is that I am not using N.

```
SELECT place collate Chinese_PRC_CI_AI from locations 
where place='ཤོགས་པ་བདེ་ལེགས།'
```

I have inserted various Tibetan words and searched them I do get the correct search results but the output is `???????????`.

Finally, it all works well when I use the datatype as `nvarchar` in the create table section above.

This is SQL  Server 2008 SP4 on Win server 2008 R2 with latest SP.

Comment: Why not use [Tibetan_100](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188046(v=sql.105).aspx). I'm pretty sure you'll need that, or to store it as `NVARCHAR` for it to display the results.

Comment: Thanks scsimon. I have tried this but the resultset is still ???????. I know that changing the datatype to nvarchar works like a charm and it works with many collations besides the Tibetian_100. But I would like to sort this out without altering the table.

Comment: You can't, because you aren't storing them as unicode. You'll need to alter that column to NVARCHAR and reinsert your data

Comment: Thats what I thought too. But whats strange here is that I can filter the data using the predicates (where clause) and it indeed gives the right output but in ?????? form. This means that its able to recognise the characters. Its just not able to show it at the console which is really strange and thats what I am after. If the table is 2TB then altering the column would be near to impossible.  -- thx Abhay